# ¿Cómo redireccionar al seleccionar una opción del combobox?

Tags: php, array, combobox

Actualmente estoy trabajando en PHP y postgreSQL.

Aquí tengo un combobox el cual esta "lleno" de datos extraídos de una base de datos.

Aquí es donde necesito su ayuda. Lo que realmente quiero es que al seleccionar una opción del combobox se redireccione una página diferente.

A continuación dejo el código con el que trabajo.

```
<?php

    include("conexion.php");
    $conn = pg_connect ($cad) or die ("Error al conectar");

    $nomUsuario=$_SESSION["nombre"];
    $usuario=$_POST[user];

    $sql ="SELECT nombre FROM login WHERE correo='$_POST[user]'";
    $busca=pg_query($sql) or die ("ERROR");
    $row=pg_fetch_array($busca);

    $selectCurso="SELECT taller FROM cursos";
    $buscaCurso=pg_query($selectCurso) or die("Error");

?>


<body link="#ffffff" vlink="#ffffff">
    <h1 align="center">Bienvenido </h1>
    <center><select name="Cursos" onchange="location=this.value"></center>

        <option value="C00">Seleccione su curso</option> 

        <?php while($curso=pg_fetch_array($buscaCurso)) { ?>

        <option value="quest0.php"> <?php echo $curso[taller];?> </option>

            <?php } ?>

    </select>
```

Comment: Intenta colocando `location.href=this.value` en el atributo onchange de tu select

Answer (score 1):

La única manera para lograrlo sería usando javascript, es sencillo y pues te llevaría un par de minutos hacerlo. Te comparto un pequeño script de como sería usando jquery.

```
$(function(){

  $('#select').on('change', function(e) {
    window.location.href = this.value;
  });

});
```